# Parameters send from Java to JNI are not being sent

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have read about on how parameters are being send from Java to a JNI function. I first tried to send an ArrayList because im trying to get Android phonebooks.

After a lot of problems I made it simple to be completely sure that a simple parameter (a String) is being send.

This is my Java declaration of the function:

```
public static native void nativeCallback(String params);
```

and this is the JNI function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_example_nativeCallback(JNIEnv*  env,jstring params)
```

I check and the function is being called. I used this to see if there is actually a String being send:

```
int sizeOfChain = env->GetStringLenght(params);
std::ostringstream convert;
convert<<sizeOfChain;
convert.flush();
std::string finalString = convert.str();
```

When printing **finalString** it is 0.

This is how the function is being called from Java:

```
nativeCallback("TEST_STRING");
```

Also, sending an ArrayList is valid as jobjectArray?

Comment: A `jstring` is not a C++ string, it's just a reference to the Java `String`. You first have to marshal the reference into a C++ `string` (char array, actually) using JNI methods. Look at `env->GetStringUTFChars()`

Comment: I'm not sure why you think an uninitialized stream is going to get data from Java, that doesn't even make sense to me.  To answer your final question-  no an array list is not a jobjectArray. It has to be an actual array.  Although you can pass down an ArrayList as a jobject.

Comment: The principal problem was that when I was trying to log the string it didnt show anything. So I used GetStringLenght to check if **params** had something but it didnt. So I deduced that params wasnt being sent.

What fixed everything was adding a jclass parameter after the JNIEnv. Now the log actually shows me the string I send. Thanks for your quick answers.

Comment: @GabeSechan, in case I want to access an element of the jarray (as jstring).How would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this to get a C string from the jstring

```
const char *str= env->GetStringUTFChars(params, NULL);

printf("String: %s\n", str);

env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(params, str);
```